# Upload file on server to google drive using javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-drive-api

I would like to allow users of my site to be able to upload files that they have created that are stored on my server to be uploaded to there google drive account.

I tried authenticated and passing this accesstoken to .net but couldnt get that flow to work.
[Using existing access token for google drive request in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266877/using-existing-access-token-for-google-drive-request-in-net)

So now i need helping in doing this with just javascript. How can i download the file in the background and then pass it to the api?

I would like to avoid using the Save to Drive button if possible.

Here is my current code:

```
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
      //How do i download a file and then pass it on.
      var file = 
      insertFile(file);
    });


  /**
   * Insert new file.
   *
   * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
   * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
   */
  function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
      var metadata = {
        'title': fileData.name,
        'mimeType': contentType
      };

      var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
      var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
          '\r\n' +
          base64Data +
          close_delim;

      var request = gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
          'method': 'POST',
          'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
          },
          'body': multipartRequestBody});
      if (!callback) {
        callback = function(file) {
          console.log(file)
        };
      }
      request.execute(callback);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples of downloading a file from GET request to binary string using XMLHttpRequest. For example, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370943/retrieving-binary-file-content-using-javascript-base64-encode-it-and-reverse-de). You can replace the part that reads file as a binary string `reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);` to this code.

Comment: Legend! Directed me to the perfect link. Was having problems using the example in the question but as soon as i actually read the post and implemented the answers it worked like a treat!

Thank you very much!!!!!!!!